# How to handle site update with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github-pages

I have an angular app hosted on github pages. When I push out a new version users who have the site partially loaded can experience problems until the page is refreshed.

I think this is maybe because the users browser has downloaded the updated version of a view. The updated view uses a new directive which is not in the modules that they had loaded in their browsers.

I can think of a multitude of hacks to get around this but surely it must be a common thing. Is there a standard way to deal with this or to structure the app to avoid these problems.

Comment: Obviously refreshing the browser is the best solution unless you want people to be able to keep their web browser open forever and keep updating the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I know myself as a user I keep the page open in a tab on my phone. That is how I found the problem. I updated the site earlier today and tonight I went to check something using my app and some information was missing. It took me a little while to realise I had to refresh. I don't think all my users would even know how to refresh a page in their browser.

Comment: This is obviously not the best answer I could give but since you're talking about github pages, you don't have any backend that you can use. Yet, you could probably store a file containing a version that can be fetched by the webapp. You could poll the file (no super), but you could probably add an error handler that will fetch the file on errors and refresh the page if the version changed. And update the version manually too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you minify your client side javascript and/or css assets you can check whether a script or stylesheet that was included in the html in the form of:

```
<script src="scripts/vendor.a2d3cfb2.js"></script>
```

Still exists on the server - if does not exist you can prompt the user to reload the app as it may be an indicator of new version of the application being deployed.

Note that this **requires** using a file that changes frequently if not always whenever a new version of the application is deployed. If you don't have such file or you application is deployed frequently with small changes you can use your `index.html` to verify *cache busters* in the links to stylesheets, javascripts in a fresh version fetched from the server have changed.

A rough sketch of a check for an updated script file:

```js
var module = angular.module('test', []);
module.run(function($interval, $http) {
  var intervalHandle;
  var scripts = [].slice.call(document.scripts);
  var testFile = scripts[0]; //use resource whose uri changes with each deploy
  intervalHandle = $interval(function() {
    $http.head(url + '?' + Date.now()) //scripts may be large avoid downloading content
      .catch(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 404 || response.status === 410) {
          alert('New version may be deployed.');
          $interval.cancel(intervalHandle);
        }
      });
  }, 5 * 1000 * 60); //every five mnutes

});
```